Rstudio Docker github tokening issue
I am running this docker image on a virtual machine that uses rocker/rstudio as the base image and I can access and use the image as normal without issue. However whenever I try to access github whether that be installing a package (devtools::install_github(...)) or on the terminal just try to clone a repo (git clone ....) it fails. Outputs:
Console:
> devtools::install_github("tidyverse/dplyr")
Error: Failed to install 'dplyr' from GitHub:
  Timeout was reached: [api.github.com] SSL connection timeout

Terminal:
$ export GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 
$ git clone https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr
Cloning into 'dplyr'...
08:36:36.785019 http.c:664              == Info: Couldn't find host github.com in the (nil) file; using defaults
08:36:36.795055 http.c:664              == Info:   Trying 20.26.156.215:443...
08:36:36.798244 http.c:664              == Info: Connected to github.com (20.26.156.215) port 443 (#0)
08:36:36.830750 http.c:664              == Info: found 411 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
08:36:36.830808 http.c:664              == Info: GnuTLS ciphers: NORMAL:-ARCFOUR-128:-CTYPE-ALL:+CTYPE-X509:-VERS-SSL3.0
08:36:36.830824 http.c:664              == Info: ALPN, offering h2
08:36:36.830831 http.c:664              == Info: ALPN, offering http/1.1
08:41:36.817732 http.c:664              == Info: SSL connection timeout
08:41:36.817801 http.c:664              == Info: Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/': SSL connection timeout

I have tested this same image locally and everything works fine. I have also tested the internet connection in the image on the virtual machine so it appears to be an issue specific with accessing github from the docker image on a virtual machine:
> curl::has_internet()
[1] TRUE

The issue is also not to do with my github PAT as I have successfully set this on the vm image:
#set it
gitcreds::gitcreds_set()
#returns the PAT
gh::gh_token()

So I guess the issue is github tokening but I have no clue how to get around it! I've also looked into some related SO posts like the answer specified here but no luck!
